# Как правильно добавлять объект в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Нужно добавить в массив объект со свойствами `x=100`, `y=500`. Но почему-то ничего не получается, в чём ошибка ?

```
var coord_arr = [];
coord_arr[0].x = 100;
coord_arr[0].y = 500;

alert( coord_arr[0].y );
```

Comment: Как Вы пытаетесь обращаться к первому элементу (`arr[0]`), если в массиве ещё пусто? Добавьте что-нибудь (по смыслу - объект), только потом обращайтесь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуй так

```js
var coord_arr = [];
coord_arr.push({x:100, y:500});
alert( coord_arr[0].y );
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного дополню ответ @akrasnov87 .  `.push` правильно использовать для наполнения именно массива. Но есть ещё в JS объекты, которые часто используются в качестве ассоциативных массивов. Такие правильно заполнять через индекс:

```js
var coord_arr = {};
coord_arr[0] = {x:100, y:500};
alert( coord_arr[0].y );
coord_arr['left_eye'] = {x:200, y:-500};
alert( coord_arr['left_eye'].y );

Object.keys(coord_arr).forEach(function(key){
  alert(key+" "+coord_arr[key].x);
});
```